# People with 'beauty handicaps' still enjoy their easy, loving relationships

Tags: meaning

> Everyone knows people with all kinds of 'beauty handicaps' who nonetheless have easy, loving relationships.

The sentence is from an article. Can I rephrase the sentence like the following?

> People with 'beauty handicaps' still enjoy their easy, loving relationships.

I'd like to know whether it is correct or not.

Comment: You would have to be careful to retain the context of this sentence if it is something you're saying/writing to another person.  You've got the meaning of it, but it's a potentially offensive sentiment to start with (Somehow even ugly people are loved!), and summarizing it makes it that much more likely to be taken in the wrong way.

Answer (score 2):

Your change to the phrasing is grammatical, but substantially changes the meaning.

Using *who nonetheless have* creates a contrast: they have *easy, loving relationships* **in spite of** their *beauty handicaps*; we would expect them to have trouble finding love given their appearance.

Contrast this with *still enjoy*, which suggests that these people would have difficulty taking pleasure in relationships. While *enjoy* can mean *possess or benefit from*, this is an uncommon and archaic usage in American English. It's also uncommon in British English in my experience, but I'm less confident calling it archaic in that context.

Even if we grant the secondary meaning of *enjoy* in this case, the phrasing doesn't carry the strong connotation of triumph in the face of adversity that the *nonetheless* construction does.